# Moving a SIte from Drupal to Raw PHP ... Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, drupal, drupal-7

I don't understand this the error,

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I am not familiar with drupal or any frameworks. Please advice me about this error and if I want to host my raw php site which I created in local WAMP server and connect to the database through, ...

```
#Database Connection 
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','****user', '***pw', '***db') OR die('Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());
```

what should I do?

Comment: Is you MySQL server running properly ?

Comment: currently a live site is there.. so i think it is running without any issue. I just wanted to move the site to live ftp and check. what i did was, creating a folder in ftp and accessed it through mydomain.com/newFolder ... then it returned this error.

Comment: it's a good time for you to explain your settings, configuration

Comment: Double check your database connection info provider gave you. Maybe host isn't "localhost" but something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether `mysql` is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

And if not try changing your permission to `mysql` folder. If you are working locally, you can try:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Reference [Connect to Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Comment: where do i have to type this? i don't have a cpanel .

Comment: In local It will be in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.Tthen ask the provider to change it...

Comment: i dont have such a file directory